# Read files from URL using ReadableByteChannel

Tags: java, file, url

We have an `HTTP` url location which holds a list of `.txt` files I want to fetch and hold them as an array of files.

After a dig around in `SO`, I manage to establish a channel to the URL location hosting the files like this.

```
  String hostedLocation = "http://mydomain.com/file/";
  URL url= new URL(hostedLocation);
  ReadableByteChannel channel = Channels.newChannel(url.openStream());
```

I am stuck at this point trying to pull all the files. Can someone help me please.

Thanks

Comment: Out of interest, do you really need to use ReadableByteChannel at all, instead of just fetching the data from the InputStream synchronously?

Comment: There we go then :) Just read from `url.openStream()` as with any other stream.

Comment: Presumably accessing this URL returns a human readable listing of the files?  First thing to do then is parse that listing in order to get the file names and then make separate requests for each of these files.

Comment: Thanks to `@JonSkeet` and `@trojanfoe` your suggestion was very valuable.

Answer (score 0):

Include `commons-io` as your dependency.

Then :

```
String content = IOUtils.toString(url.openStream());
```

Comment: Is there a pure Java solution?